# Floating point arithmetic in IEEE standard floating point arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods

If real numbers a and b satisfy $a<b$, is it necessary for $fl\left(a\right)<fl\left(b\right)$ to be true? I think it is true because neither rounding the numbers or chopping them would change the order, but I don't know how to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: there are many $a \ne b$ for which $fl(a) = fl(b)$, so replace $<$ by $\le$ (and be careful, it is not so easy to create an algorithm for converting $a \in \mathbb{R}$ to $fl(a)$ such that $a \le b \implies fl(a) \le fl(b)$)

Comment: What about "If $a\lt b$, then $fl\left(a\right)\le fl\left(b\right)$"?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specifically define $fl(a)$.  If you define $fl(a)$ as the floating point number that is closest to $a$, then $a \lt b \implies fl(a) \le fl(b)$ is true.  If you round properly, each floating point representation corresponds to an interval of $\Bbb R$, the intervals are all disjoint and maintain the order.

Comment: If I define $fl\left(a\right)$ as the floating number that is closest to a, and the same with $fl\left(b\right)$, then I prove the monotonicity of it. Then can I directly say that if there is a number c satisfying $c= \left(a+b\right)\div 2$, then $a\le fl\left(c\right)\le b$?

Comment: No, because $a$ and $b$ could be between the same floating point numbers.  Imagine two neighboring floats were $1,1.1$ and take $a=1.03,b=1.05$.  Then $c=1.04, fl(c)=1$.  By raising $a,b$ we could make $fl(c)=1.1$

Comment: If we make $fl\left(c\right) = 1.1$, then a and b got raised to something bigger, it could still be true that $a\le fl\left(c\right)\le b$?

Comment: It could be true, but I was showing that you couldn't guarantee that $fl(c)$ is between $a$ and $b$.  In fact there may not be a floating number between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: I like the image your words generated in my mind: a sequence of disjoint intervals covering the representable range, with one interval $I_f$ per floating point number f, and $\text{fl}(x) = f$ for all $x \in I_f$. This image "clearly" shows that the mapping from real to floating point numbers is monotone increasing. At least it works for me.

Whether or not a particular endpoint belongs to an interval depends on the location of the interval and/or the rounding mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is false in general. $1$ is an IEEE floating point number. Let $u$ denote the unit round off error. Then $\text{fl}(1+u) = 1$. However, you have the weaker statement that if $x \leq y$ are both in the representable range, then $\text{fl}(x) \leq \text{fl}(y)$.

Let $0 < a < b$. By scaling by a power of 2 we can ensure that $1 \leq a < 2$. If $b \geq 2$, then there is nothing to show, because $2$ is a floating point number, so $2 \leq \text{fl}(b)$. Now, on the interval $[1,2)$ the floating point numbers are nicely spaced and can be written as $f_n = 1 + n\cdot \epsilon$, where $\epsilon = 2u$. Now find $n$ such that $f_n \leq a < f_{n+1}$. The floating point representation of $a$ will be either $f_n$ or $f_{n+1}$. If $f_{n+1} \leq b$, then there is nothing too show. If $b < f_{n+1}$, then $f_n \leq a < b < f_{n+1}$. If $\text{fl}(a) = f_n$, then all is well. If $\text{fl}(a) = f_{n+1}$, then we must have $\text{fl}(b) = f_{n+1}$ because $b$ is even closer to this floating point number than $a$ is.

Comment: What about "If $a\lt b$, then $fl\left(a\right)\le fl\left(b\right)$"? But how to prove it?

Comment: I have added a paragraph on this issue,

Comment: The proof is pretty elegant, but I don't think we can restrict a and b to be positive because according to the problem, we only know that a and b are real numbers and $a\lt b$ and nothing more.

Comment: @J.doe:  If $a,b$ are negative, just invert them and use the same argument.  If $a \lt 0, b \gt 0$, then $0=fl(0)$ is between them.