# Proving that $a\le \text{fl}\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\le b$

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are some floating point numbers such that $a\lt b$.  How can I show that $$a\le \text{fl}\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\le b$$
specifically in IEEE standard floating point arithmetic? In this, for example $\text{fl}(a)$ refers to the floating point number closest so some value $a$.

Comment: The IEEE spec is a pain in the next to work in, but I suspect you still have $a+a\leq a+b\leq b+b$ and then if $x\leq y$ then $x/2\leq y/2$.

Comment: By the way "fl" is not a normal math notation, so you should describe what you mean. I first took it to mean the "floor" function, but that would then make it untrue.

Comment: How does $\frac{x+y}{2}$ differ from $fl\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$. And don't clarify in comments, update your question. Answerers should not have to read the comments to understand your question. @steve

Comment: This Question, if I've read it correctly, does not concern floating-point arithmetic so much as it does floating-point representable numbers.

Comment: @steve:  I'm not trying to "change anything", just to draw attention to the nub of the problem:  Where on the number line will the (exactly) FP representable number closest to $\frac{a+b}{2}$ lie?  All you need to do is rule out values less than $a$ or greater than $b$.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35274/discussion-on-question-by-steve-proving-that-a-le-textfl-left-fracab2). I deleted the comments revolving around questions about IEEE format and what the question is about, and put all of them in a chatroom. If you have more such concerns, please check out that chatroom first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem does not require us to carry out or exploit properties of floating point arithmetic, as it defines $fl((a+b)/2)$ simply as that floating-point representable number closest to $(a+b)/2$.  Note that this is a slight misstatement, in that "closest" may not uniquely determine $fl((a+b)/2)$, but this will not affect our reasoning to the conclusion below.

Now the floating-point representable numbers are a finite subset of the real numbers, so given that $a,b$ are (exactly) floating point numbers, with:

$$ a \lt b $$

there are only three possibilities:

$$ fl\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) \lt a \lt b $$

$$ a \le fl\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) \le b $$

$$ a \lt b \lt fl\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) $$

So we ask ourselves which of these are sensible.  Is it possible that the closest floating-point representable number to the actual value of $(a+b)/2$ is less than $a$ or greater than $b$?  Clearly the actual value is strictly between $a$ and $b$.

Therefore any floating-point number less than $a$ cannot be as close as $a$ is to $(a+b)/2$, nor can any floating-point number greater than $b$ be as close as $b$ is to $(a+b)/2$.

Hence only the middle possibility is viable.

Comment: Put another way: since $a$ is assumed representable, if you have a candidate $c$ for $fl((a+b)/2)$ which is less than $a$, $a$ is a representable number which is closer to $(a+b)/2$ than $c$ is, so $c$ is not the representation. Analogous for the other endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we have $x < y$ implies that $\text{fl}(x) \leq \text{fl}(y)$, see
[Floating point arithmetic in IEEE standard floating point arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635021/floating-point-arithmetic-in-ieee-standard-floating-point-arithmetic/1635061#1635061) 
This property also solves the problem.

It is interesting to note that the *computed* average need not fall in the interval between $a$ and $b$, at least not in base 10. Here $a=6.377$ and $b=6.379$ provides a counterexample when the calculations are done with four significant figures. The true sum is $s=12.756$ which rounds to $\hat{s} = 12.76$. Division by $2$ then yields the computed average of $\hat{\mu} = 6.380$ which is larger than either of $a$ and $b$!